# Euler-Poincaré characteristic and homology

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups

### The problem

$\DeclareMathOperator{rk}{\text{rk}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{im}{\text{im}}$
Let 
$$C = ( C_n \overset{\partial_n}\to C_{n-1} \overset{\partial_{n-1}}\to \dots \overset{\partial_2}\to C_1 \overset{\partial_1}\to C_0 ) $$ be a chain complex of finitely-generated **free** abelian groups, and define its Euler-Poincaré characteristic by the formula
$$ \chi(C) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i} \,\text{rk}(C_i) $$
It's straightforward to prove that $\chi(D)$ vanishes for a short exact sequence of abelian groups. Now I'm asked to use that result to show that
$$ \chi(C) = \chi(H(C)), $$ 
where $\chi(H(C))$ is the homology complex of $C$, in the natural sense.

---

### My Solution

Define $Z_i = \ker(\partial_i)$ and $B_{i-1} = \im(\partial_i)$.
In our original chain complex $C$ we have levelwise short exact sequences
$$ 0\to Z_i \to C_i \to B_{i-1} \to 0, $$

while in the homology complex we have levelwise short exact sequences of the form
$$ 0\to B_i \to Z_i \to H_i \to 0. $$
Since both $B_{i-1}$ and $H_i$ are free abelian group, so equivalently free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, they are in particular projective modules. Hence the above sequences split, giving 
$$C_i = B_{i-1}\oplus Z_{i} \quad \implies \quad\rk(C_i) = \rk(B_{i-1}) - \rk(Z_{i})$$
and
$$Z_i = B_i\oplus H_i \quad \implies \quad\rk(H_i) = \rk(Z_i) - \rk(B_i).$$

Thus keeping in mind that $B_{-1} = B_{n} = 0$, we find
$$
\chi(C) - \chi(H(C))  = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i} \,\text{rk}(C_i) - \text{rk}(H_i) = (-1)^n B_n - B_{-1} = 0 $$

---

### Questions

1. How can one extend this to a chain complex made of **non necessarily free** abelian groups?
2. Do you agree with my solution? Do you have any remark to add?
3. Are there any problems generalizing this to free $R$-module, for a ring $R$ with the Invariant Basis Number property?

Comment: 1. I started reading about homological algebra only a few days ago but this is the proof I saw for this result. So yes, I think it's correct.

2. I don't see why not !

Comment: "Since both $B_{i−1}$ and $H_i$ are abelian group, so equivalently free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules" -- why???

Comment: There is no homology *complex*. It is only a sequence of abelian groups. The rank function can be replaced by any function which is well-defined, finite and additive on short exact sequences of the abelian groups in consideration, or more generally within an abelian category. For arbitrary abelian groups, you will get problems because the rank may be infinite.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : You are right, we need the abelian grops to be finitely generated.
Why don't we get a complex in homology? We can use zero maps in the sequence, right?

Comment: @BorisNovikov : Thanks for pointing this out! My argument only works for free groups, and I edited the question accordingly. Do you know how to fix it to work for non necessarily free groups?

Comment: The rank of an abelian group is additive on short exact sequences. You don't need split exact sequences, because they become split after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ by linear algebra, and the rank is (by definition) the dimension of this vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Abramodj: Why don't you want to use 
S.Lang, "Algebra", 3rd ed., sec.III.8 "Euler-Poincaré maps"?

Comment: Even if the complex consists of free abelian groups, its homology can contain non-free abelian groups.  Use Martin Brandenburg's second comment to avoid any mention of splitting and freeness.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a Euler-Poincaré map. We have the so called "fundamental" short exact sequences

$$0\longrightarrow B_n\longrightarrow Z_n \longrightarrow H_n \longrightarrow 0\\
0 \longrightarrow Z_n \longrightarrow C_n \longrightarrow B_{n+1} \longrightarrow 0$$
so that $P(C_n)=P(Z_n)+P(B_{n+1})$ and $ P(Z_n)=P(B_n)+P(H_n)$
Then $$\begin{align}\chi(C)&= \sum (-1)^i P(C_i)\\&=\sum (-1)^i P(Z_i) + \sum  (-1)^i P(B_{i+1})\\&=\sum (-1)^i P(Z_i) - \sum (-1)^i P(B_i)\\&=\sum (-1)^i P(H_i)=\chi(H(C))\end{align}$$

This proves for example that weakly equivalent complexes have equal characterisitc. In partiular homotopy equivalent complexes have equal characterisitc, so indeed this characteristic is an homotopy invariant.

Comment: Playful remark: $\chi$ is an Euler-Poincaré map on the category of complexes. The two short exact sequences give rise to short exact sequences of complexes. $\chi(B_*) = -\chi(B_{*+1})$ and we directly see, that $\chi(C) = \chi(Z)-\chi(B) = \chi(H(C))$.

Comment: @JulianQuast That's the point of this thread, isn't it? ;)